# Python replace first character in every element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example lets say I have a list `['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']` and another list as `['i','t','t','a']` and I want to produce `['ihis', 'ts', 't', 'aest']`. I tried to do a for loop but it would not let me delete anything because it is immutable.

I tried:

```
for i in list1: del i[0]
```

Comment: the fourth element of the result is `aest` right?

Comment: yes, my bad i changed it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension like this:

```
test_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

first_letters = ['i','t','t','a']

[letter+word[1:] for letter, word in zip(first_letters, test_list)]

# ['ihis', 'ts', 't', 'aest']
```

The `zip` function essentially creates this list of tuples (it's actually an *iterator* of tuples, but for simplicity, it can be thought of as a list):

```
[('i', 'this'), ('t', 'is'), ('t', 'a'), ('a', 'test')]
```

Which the list comprehension iterates through, returning a new list with the `letter` (first element of each tuple) and all letters starting from the second letter of the `word` (second element of the tuple)

It is essentially equivalent to the following loop, if you prefer that syntax:

```
result = []

for letter, word in zip(first_letters, test_list):
    result.append(letter+word[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, strings are immutable in Python. That means you have to build a *new* string to replace the old one. And you have to store that new string—either back in the original list, or in a new list.

If you want to store them back in the original list, you need the index as well as the value:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
    list[idx] = i[1:]
```

If you want to create a new list, you just `append` them as they come in, or use a comprehension:

```
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i[1:])

list2 = [i[1:] for i in list1]
```

Usually creating a new list is better (which is why Python has a syntactic shortcut for only that one), but sometimes mutating in-place is better (which is why that one isn't too much more verbose or difficult). The question is: If any other piece of code had made another reference to `list1`, would you want it to see the changed version, or the original version?

Answer (score 0):

you can try range method :

```
test_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

first_letters = ['i','t','t','a']



print([first_letters[i]+test_list[i][1:]for i in range(len(test_list))])
```

output:

```
['ihis', 'ts', 't', 'aest']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
y = ['i','t','t','a']
z = [y + x[1:] for x, y in zip(x, y)]
print(z)
```

z = ['ihis', 'ts', 't', 'aest']

Comment: You can use unpack on each element of zip result.